# How to access user coordinates

Tags: swift, location, maps

I am trying to access the users coordinates using:

```
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    let userCoordinates = (locationManager.location?.coordinate)!
}
```

However, it crashes upon the simulator loading. I set the simulator location to Apple, and input privacy keys into info.plist, but I am not sure why this is not grabbing the user location.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you need to do first before you can start using a device's current geolocation safely and based on the code you provided I'm going to assume that you might be missing some so here is a common set up using a Google Map, which acts like any other basically:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    // properties
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var currentCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D?

    // load view
    override func loadView() {
        addLocationManager()
    }

    // add location manager
    func addLocationManager() {

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    }

    // location manager delegate: did change authorization
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

        switch status {

        case .restricted:
            print("LOCATION ACCESS RESTRICTED")

        case .denied:
            print("LOCATION ACCESS DENIED")

        case .notDetermined:
            print("LOCATION ACCESS NOT DETERMINED")

        case .authorizedAlways:
            fallthrough

        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            print("LOCATION STATUS GRANTED")

        }

    }


    // location manager delegate: did fail with error
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {

        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        print("LOCATION ACCESS ERROR: \(error)")

    }


    // location manager delegate: did update locations
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        let lastLocation = locations.last!

        // unhide map when current location is available
        if mapView.isHidden {
            mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: lastLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: lastLocation.coordinate.longitude, zoom: 18, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)
            mapView.isHidden = false
        }

        // update current location properties
        currentCoordinate = lastLocation.coordinate

    }


}
```

And no need to import `CoreLocation` if you've imported `MapKit`.